# How to achieve "unformatted" format specifier in write/read statements?

Tags: io, fortran, read-write

I'd like to be able to switch easily between formatted and unformatted output. But for the `write` and `read` statements, there is no format-specifier for unformatted output, as far as I know --- only the option to remove the specifier. Must I use an `if`-statement on every `read` and `write` to achieve this flexibility, or is there better way around this?

Comment: You shouldn't put tags into the question title if it is not a natural part of it  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2):

Unformatted and formatted I/O is so different that you can have just two versions of your subroutines or one big `if`. Especially if you have many `read` and `write` statements.

If you use already the C preprocessor, you could also define a macro for the write and use an include file to avoid code duplication, but I wouldn't introduce it just for this.

If you actually meant to mix formatted and unformatted in a single file, you could use unformatted stream access and store character strings there in the "formatted" portions. Or close, re-open with `position="append"` and change your `form=`.

Comment: I didn't intend to mix them. In my case the code is basically unaltered outside of a few read/write statements. It's mostly a matter of speed vs. compatibility. If-statements might have to do the job.